# array of objects

Tags: android, json, arraylist

For post method in android
I have to send array of objects. 
I am retrieving elements from an arrayList and putting that retrieved element in JSONObject and than putting that in JSONobject in JSONArray.

```
JSONArray ccArray = new JSONArray();
{
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    if (ccArrayList.size() != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ccArrayList.size(); i++) {
            object.put("emailId", ccArrayList.get(i));
            ccArray.put(object);
        }
    } else {
        object.put("", "");
    }
}
```

When there are more than 2 or more than 2 elements in arraylist it is adding the last element in ccrray as many times as their are elements in the list.

> output :
>   `"cc":[{"emailId":"f@j.com"},{"emailId":"f@j.com"}]`

Comment: you need to put your JSONArray into a JSONObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Change code like this

```
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray ccArray = new JSONArray();

                for (int i = 0; i < ccArrayList.size(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
                    if (ccArrayList.size() != 0) {

                        object.put("emailId", ccArrayList.get(i));
                        ccArray.put(object);

                    } else {
                        object.put("", "");
                    }
                }
            obj.put("cc",ccArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Code:-

```
ArrayList<String> ccArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
ccArrayList.add("abc@xyz.com");
ccArrayList.add("abc@xyz.com");
ccArrayList.add("abc@xyz.com");
ccArrayList.add("abc@xyz.com");
ccArrayList.add("abc@xyz.com");

JSONArray ccArray = new JSONArray();

if(ccArrayList.size()>0){

    for(int i=0;i<ccArrayList.size();i++){

        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        try {
            object.put("emailId", ccArrayList.get(i));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ccArray.put(object);
    }
}
```

Output:-

```
ccArray: [{"emailId":"abc@xyz.com"},{"emailId":"abc@xyz.com"},{"emailId":"abc@xyz.com"},{"emailId":"abc@xyz.com"},{"emailId":"abc@xyz.com"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you declared `JSONObject object = new JSONObject();` outside the `for` loop, so each time it loops the `object` adds a new `JSONObject` and also does the array. Try keeping it within the loop:

```
JSONArray ccArray = new JSONArray();
for (int i = 0; i < ccArrayList.size(); i++) {
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    object.put("emailId", ccArrayList.get(i));
    ccArray.put(object);
}
```